# Imported CSV file has incorrect column values in BigQuery

Tags: file-upload, google-bigquery

I uploaded a local CSV file into BigQuery, but two nullable columns show incorrect values.

All the values for the 'School_Name' column are 'Default', and all the values for the 'School_Code' column are '0'. Both the 'School_Name' and 'School_Code' are 'text' type in CSV and String type in BigQuery.

Any ideas or suggestions to figure out this problem will be appreciated.

I have tried the following two ways, but got the same result with incorrect column values for 'School_Name' and 'School_Code'. All other columns values are correct.

1. Uploaded the CSV file to BigQuery and create a table by using the existing schema.
2. Create a table in BigQuery first, and then upload the CSV file to the created table in BigQuery.

Comment: Maybe BQ defined your 'School_Code' as integer?

Answer (score 0):

Many factors are a possible cause of this(value mismatched to data type etc etc), I would suggest visiting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#limitations) for loading csv files to BQ.

One of the notable limitations:

> BigQuery does not guarantee data consistency for external data sources. Changes to the underlying data while a query is running can result in unexpected behaviour.

The documentation also includes good guidelines to keep in mind when loading in to bigquery.

Comment: Hi, Nestor! Thanks for your inputs! I'll read the documentation for loading csv files to BQ.